# meant or was meant to do

Tags: sentence-meaning

I saw some times we say it was meant to be,  in the other hand, we might say he meant that. If so, we will have several collocations with these. Can I say he was meant to do or it meant that. Furthermore, does it was.meant to be and it meant that have any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

***Was meant to*** and  ***meant to/that*** convey different meanings:

***[be meant to:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-meant-to-do-something)***

> to have a particular responsibility or duty:
>
> - You were meant to keep the children out of trouble.

***[To mean:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/mean)***

> to intend:
>
> - I'm sorry if I offended you - I didn't mean any harm.